# Samsung J5 stuck in boot loop after factory reset

Tags: boot-loop, boot

- Phone was rooted and working fine
- I did a factory reset

Now, it seems to just boot into the Samsung animating logo that does not go away...

I'm able to boot into the recovery mode and view the logs. which has logs of:

```
couldn't find any tzdata when looking for localtime
...
can't open /dev/tt0: No such file or directory
...
no adf devices
```

Any chance to salvage this?

Answer (score 0):

flash the same stock boot.img. its in BL_J500xxxxxx.
extract from it or flash the whole BL_J500xxxxx.
for extraction use 7zip,
then right click on the boot.img > add to archive
make boot.tar
flash it in AP, using odin